# Equality Comes in Threes

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

## Taken from: OEIS-[A071816](http://oeis.org/A071816)

Your task, given an upper bound of `n`, is to find the number of solutions that satisfy the equation:

```
a+b+c = x+y+z, where 0 <= a,b,c,x,y,z < n
```

The sequence starts out as described on the OEIS page, and as below (1-indexed):

```
1, 20, 141, 580, 1751, 4332, 9331, 18152, 32661, 55252, 88913, 137292, 204763, 296492, 418503, 577744, 782153, 1040724, 1363573, 1762004, 2248575, 2837164, 3543035, 4382904, 5375005, 6539156, 7896825, 9471196, 11287235, 13371756
```

---

For `n = 1`, there's only one solution: `(0,0,0,0,0,0)`

For `n = 2`, there are 20 ordered solutions `(a,b,c,x,y,z)` to `a+b+c = x+y+z`:

```
(0,0,0,0,0,0), (0,0,1,0,0,1), (0,0,1,0,1,0), (0,0,1,1,0,0), (0,1,0,0,0,1), 
(0,1,0,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1,0,0), (0,1,1,0,1,1), (0,1,1,1,0,1), (0,1,1,1,1,0), 
(1,0,0,0,0,1), (1,0,0,0,1,0), (1,0,0,1,0,0), (1,0,1,0,1,1), (1,0,1,1,0,1), 
(1,0,1,1,1,0), (1,1,0,0,1,1), (1,1,0,1,0,1), (1,1,0,1,1,0), (1,1,1,1,1,1).
```

---

## I & O

- Input is a single integer denoting `n`.
- Output is a single integer/string denoting `f(n)`, where `f(...)` is the function above.
- The indexing is exactly as described, no other indexing is acceptable.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: Ahhh crappp, I didn't notice the direct formula on OEIS, I thought this wouldn't be *that* easy. Oh well, I'm not +1'ing direct ports of that equation ;P.

Comment: At least the formula wasn't perfectly golfed :P

Comment: Then again, it gives reg-langs a chance against the eso-langs.

Comment: Would it be better if the title is "equality comes in triplets"?

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
ṗ6ḅ-ċ0
```

**O(n<sup>6</sup>)** solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w53SzhztadY90G/z//98UAA)

#### How it works

```
ṗ6ḅ-ċ0  Main link. Argument: n

ṗ6      Cartesian power 6; build all 6-tuples (a, x, b, y, c, z) of integers in
        [1, ..., n]. The challenge spec mentions [0, ..., n-1], but since there
        are three summands on each side, this doesn't matter.
  ḅ-    Unbase -1; convert each tuple from base -1 to integer, mapping (a, ..., z)
        to a(-1)**5 + x(-1)**4 + b(-1)**3 + y(-1)**2 + c(-1)**1 + z(-1)**0, i.e.,
        to -a + x - b + y - c + z = (x + y + z) - (a + b + c). This yields 0 if and
        only if the 6-tuple is a match.
    ċ0  Count the number of zeroes.
```

Comment: Ha! Gotta love the theoretical answers (my basis for a theoretical answer is now *does it run on TIO for large values of n*, this is probably bad). I was hoping to see a `O(n^6)` though :P.

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica 17 or 76 Bytes

Using the formula:

```
.55#^5+#^3/4+#/5&
```

(Saved 3 bytes per @GregMartin and @ngenisis)

Rather than using the formula, here I literally compute all the solutions and count them.

```
Length@Solve[a+b+c==x+y+z&&And@@Table[(0<=i<#),{i,{a,b,c,x,y,z}}],Integers]&
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the non-brute-force way :). +1 for any mathematica answer that isn't an equation or a built-in.

Comment: As per [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118035/56178), you can replace `11/20` by `.55` for a two-byte savings.

Comment: You also don't need the asterisk in the first term.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

I didn't notice the formula before writing this, so it's definitely not the shortest (or fastest) general method, but I thought it was pretty.

```hs
f n=sum[1|0<-foldr1(-)<$>pure[1..n]`mapM`[1..6]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#HctLCoMwFEbhrfwDBzrw4vXVCtoddAUSMDQJFZpEosFJ954@ZocPjpWrm1Z36CAfRxbd6YPaycot35/@JENBS1XQn5OBm/ZoZ35XY2n8SwXOy2LMblsMemYiJ5bvel9@3QuREqNGgxYdelxwxQCuwAyuwQ24BXcf)

`f n` generates all lists of 6 elements from `[1..n]`, then counts the ones whose alternating sum is 0. Uses the fact that `a+b+c==d+e+f` is the same as `a-(d-(b-(e-(c-f))))==0`, and also that it doesn't matter if we add a 1 to all the numbers.

Comment: I've noticed that, often, the shortest answer is the least impressive ;). This is a pretty cool use of fold that I wouldn't've considered before seeing this answer.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
l6:"G:gY+]X>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@59jZqXkbpUeqR0bYff/v6EBAA)

#### Explanation

I couldn't miss the chance to use convolution again!

This makes use of the following characterization from OEIS:

> `a(n) = largest coefficient of (1+...+x^(n-1))^6`

and of course polynomial multiplication is convolution.

```
l        % Push 1
6:"      % Do the following 6 times
  G:g    %   Push a vector of n ones, where n is the input
  Y+     %   Convolution
]        % End
X>       % Maximum
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
JsM^UQ3s/LJJ
```

Saved one byte thanks to Leaky Nun.

Explanation

```
JsM^UQ3s/LJJ
   ^UQ3         Get all triples in the range.
JsM             Save the sums as J.
        /LJJ    Count occurrences of each element of J in J.
       s        Take the sum.
```

Comment: +1 for not using the direct formula :P.

Comment: You might like to post a link to the [online interpreter](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JsM%5EUQ3sm%2FJdJ&input=5&debug=0).

Comment: Also, you can use `/LJJ` instead of `m/JdJ`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ṗ3S€ĠL€²S
```

Not as short as @Dennis's, but it finishes in under 20 seconds for input `100`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w53Tj4EdNa44s8AGShzYF////3xQA)

#### How it works

```
ṗ3S€ĠL€²S  Main link. Argument: n

ṗ3         Cartesian power; yield all subsets of [1, ..., n] of length 3.
  S€       Sum each. 
    Ġ      Group indices by their values; for each unique sum S, list all indices whose
           values are equal to S.
     L€    Length each; for each unique sum S, yield the number of items in the original
           array that sum to S.
       ²   Square each; for each unique sum S, yield the number of pairs that both sum to S.
        S  Sum; yield the total number of equal pairs.
```

Comment: Can you explain this method? I'm currently in the process of learning Jelly, but I'm still not good enough to submit real answers yet; I always look to you, Dennis and a few others for good examples.

Comment: @carusocomputing Finished the explanation. Let me know if you still have any questions :-)

Comment: Awesome, I'm mostly confused on the optimization of answers from the most basic of brute-force implementation that I would do to the crazy short code I see you guys posting; but I feel like every explanation is a step closer thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda n:.55*n**5+n**3/4+n/5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ6VnaqqVp6Vlqg0kjPVNtPP0Tf8XFGXmlWhEp2lkaiqk5RcpZCpk5ikUJealp2oY6hgZaMZq/gcA)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, [19 bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/59183)

```
:Prompt X
:.05X(11X^4+5X²+4
```

Evaluates the OEIS formula.

Comment: How are you counting the bytes here? `Prompt x` = 2 bytes?

Comment: @carusocomputing [TI-BASIC is scored by tokens](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/59183)

Comment: Kinda sad that I've posted a TI-BASIC answer 5 times before and never scored it correctly now that I look through my history ._.

Answer (score 2):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 17 bytes

```
5m11*n3m5*nz++20÷

5                   n 5             implicit n for illustration
 m                  n**5
  11                n**5 11
    *               11*n**5
     n              11*n**5 n
      3             11*n**5 n 3
       m            11*n**5 n**3
        5           11*n**5 n**3 5
         *          11*n**5 5*n**3
          n         11*n**5 5*n**3 n
           z        11*n**5 5*n**3 4*n
            +       11*n**5 5*n**3+4*n
             +      11*n**5+5*n**3+4*n
              20    11*n**5+5*n**3+4*n 20
                ÷  (11*n**5+5*n**3+4*n)÷20
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/oasis#@59nmmtoqJVnnGuqlVelrW1kcHj7////TQE)

Oasis is a stack-based language optimized for recurring sequences. However, the recursion formula would be too long for this case.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
{>ℕ|↰}ᶠ⁶ḍD+ᵐ=∧D≜ᶜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#ASoA1f//ez7ihJV84oawfeG2oOKBtuG4jUQr4bWQPeKIp0TiiZzhtpz//zEw/1o)

#### Explanation

```
{  |↰}ᶠ⁶           Generate a list of 6 variables [A,B,C,D,E,F]...
 >ℕ                  ...which are all in the interval [0, Input)
        ḍD         Dichotomize; D = [[A,B,C],[D,E,F]]
          +ᵐ=      A + B + C must be equal to D + E + F
             ∧
              D≜ᶜ  Count the number of possible ways you can label the elements of D while
                     satisfying the constraints they have
```

Comment: I guess `ᶜ` should automatically come with `≜`

Comment: @LeakyNun You can't run `ᶜ` by itself, it's a metapredicate.

Comment: But still if it is used on a list, labeling that list could be made the default predicate, no?

Comment: @mat It could be made that way, but right now you cannot use a metapredicate on a variable.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 24 bytes

```javascript
x=>11*x**5/20+x**3/4+x/5
```

Uses the formula from the OEIS page.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#DcU5DsIwAEXBnpNkeYr9vWQpzEUQBUKEJmBLaXx7wzSzp1bTVRrqMETj7PjfmzBWE1tJN@HwBCIzCysbskjIIY8CimhGC1rRhrP3yzN/z3y8piO/uzJ9HqXb@779AA)

Comment: I think you can save two bytes with `x=>x**5*.55+x**3/4+x/5`

Comment: @ETHproductions there are floating point errors if I use *.55 instead of *11/20

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```matlab
@(n).55*n^5+n^3/4+n/5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7PV09P776CRp2loqJUXZ6pvZKCdF2esb6Kdp2/6P03DUJMrTcMIRBiDCBPN/wA)

Uses the formula from the OEIS-entry. Saved <s>two</s> four bytes by rearranging the formula and using `.55` instead of `11/20`, thanks to fəˈnɛtɪk.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, <strike>109</strike> <strike>105</strike> <strike>99</strike> 96 bytes

Thanks ETHproductions and Dennis for saving a few bytes:

```
from itertools import*
lambda s:sum(sum(x[:3])==sum(x[3:])for x in product(range(s),repeat=6))
```

Comment: Interesting, doesn't Python 3 have shorter range functions than 2.7?

Comment: `sum(sum(x[:3])==sum(x[3:])for x ...)` would be even shorter. Also, `from itertools import*` saves a byte.

Comment: You don't need the space before `for`. Also, we don't require functions to be named by default, so you can remove `h=`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 41 bytes

```matlab
@(n)round(max(ifft(fft(~~(1:n),n^2).^6)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkadZlF@al6KRm1ihkZmWVqIBwnV1GoZWeZo6eXFGmnpxZpqamv/TFGwVEvOKrbnSNAw1dRTSNIzApCmYNDSACBlo/gcA)

Similar to my [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118057/36398), but computes the convolution via a discrete Fourier transform (`fft`) with a sufficient number of points (`n^2`). `~~(1:n)` is used as a shorter version of `ones(1,n)`. `round` is necessary because of floating point errors.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 52 bytes

Kelly Lowder's implementation of the OEIS formula is way shorter, but this computes the numbers directly:

```
Count[Tr/@#~Partition~3&/@Range@#~Tuples~6,{n_,n_}]&
```

Well, it actually counts the number of solutions with `1 <= a,b,c,x,y,z <= n`. This is the same number, since adding 1 to all the variables doesn't change the equality.

Explanation: `Range@#~Tuples~6` makes all lists of six integers between 1 and n, `#~Partition~3&/@` splits each list into two lists of length 3, `Tr/@` sums these sublists, and `Count[...,{n_,n_}]` counts how many pairs have the same sum. I got very lucky with the order of precedence between `f @`, `f /@` and `~f~`!

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 17 bytes

```
ri,6m*{3/::+:=},,
```

Input of `11` times out on TIO, and `12` and higher run out of memory.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UqWOWq1VtrG9lpW1lW6uj8/@/OQA)

**Explanation**

```
ri                e# Read an int from input.
  ,               e# Generate the range 0 ... input-1.
   6m*            e# Take the 6th Cartesian power of the range.
      {           e# Keep only the sets of 6 values where:
       3/         e#  The set split into (two) chunks of 3
         ::+:=    e#  Have the sums of both chunks equal.
              },  e# (end of filter)
                , e# Get the length of the resulting list.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 79 bytes

```
#(count(for[r[(range %)]a r b r c r x r y r z r :when(=(+ a b c)(+ x y z))]1))
```

Tons of repetition in the code, on larger number of variables a macro might be shorter.